# Mixed / complex text node inc FontAwsome for buttons and tags

Tags: button, html5-canvas, konvajs

I needed to make buttons and labels with a mixture of Arial and Fontawsome. The HTML 5 canvas is relatively crude in terms of any mixing of fonts, and though Konvajs has the convenience Label shape it does not accommodate Shapes other than a single text node, as far as I can see. Take a look at my answer snippet to see what I wanted, and how I solved it.

Comment: Hey Mr Downvoter - how about you explain why you downvoted the question? In case you are unaware, it is perfectly valid to answer your own question which did as a way of finding the solution again when I forget it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. The only trick is the centering of the text for which we have to use the shape.getWidth() method and store the total width and width of each element for final positioning.

Seems to work.

```js
var s1 = new Konva.Stage({container: 'container1', width: 200, height: 200});
var layer1 = new Konva.Layer({draggable: false});
var bg1 = new Konva.Rect({width: 200, height: 200, fill: 'gold', })
layer1.add(bg1);
s1.add(layer1);


        function MakeComplexText(opts){
            var yOffset = 6;
            var txtEle = [];
            var maxW = 0;
            var g = new Konva.Group({x: opts.pos.x, y: opts.pos.y});
            g.add(new Konva.Rect({width: opts.pos.w, height: opts.pos.h, fill: opts.bgClr, stroke: opts.lineClr, strokeWidth: 1, cornerRadius: opts.cornerRadius}));

            if (opts.symbolLeft != ""){
                var t1 = new Konva.Text({name: 'symText1', y: yOffset + 1, width: 15, text: opts.symbolLeft, fontFamily: 'FontAwesome', fontSize: 11, fill: opts.textClr, align: 'left'});
                txtEle.push({obj: t1, w: t1.getWidth()});
                maxW = maxW + t1.getWidth();
                g.add(t1);
            }

            var t = new Konva.Text({name: 'btnText', y: yOffset, height: opts.pos.h, text: opts.text, fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 11, fontStyle: "Bold", fill: opts.textClr, align: 'center'})
            txtEle.push({obj: t, w: t.getWidth()});
            maxW = maxW + t.getWidth();
            g.add(t);

            if (opts.symbolRight != ""){
                var t2 = new Konva.Text({name: 'symText2', y: yOffset + 1, width: 15, text: opts.symbolRight, fontFamily: 'FontAwesome', fontSize: 11, fill: opts.textClr, align: 'right'});
                txtEle.push({obj: t2, w: t2.getWidth()});
                maxW = maxW + t2.getWidth();
                g.add(t2);
            }
          
            var xPos = (opts.pos.w - maxW)/2;
            for (var i = 0; i < txtEle.length; i = i + 1){
                txtEle[i].obj.x(xPos);
                xPos = xPos + txtEle[i].w;
            }

            opts.parent.add(g);
            return g;
        }


        // move button icon right only
        var btnModeMoveR = MakeComplexText(
          {parent: layer1, pos: {x:5, y:7, w: 75, h: 24}, text: "Move", textClr: "#666666", bgClr: "#cccccc", lineClr: "#666666", symbolLeft: "", symbolRight: "\uf047", cornerRadius: 0}
        );

        // move button with icons left & right
        var btnModeMoveL = MakeComplexText(
          {parent: layer1, pos: {x:5, y:37, w: 75, h: 24}, text: "Move", textClr: "#666666", bgClr: "#cccccc", lineClr: "#666666", symbolLeft: "\uf047", symbolRight: "\uf047", cornerRadius: 0}
        );

        // Reresh button icon left
        var btnModeMoveL = MakeComplexText(
          {parent: layer1, pos: {x:5, y:67, w: 75, h: 24}, text: "Refresh", textClr: "#666666", bgClr: "#cccccc", lineClr: "#666666", symbolLeft: "", symbolRight: "\uf021", cornerRadius: 0}
        );


      // to make a tooltip we combine a label and complex text in a group. 

      var g = new Konva.Group({ x: 5, y: 97});

      var tooltip = new Konva.Label({x: 0, y: 0, width: 100});
      tooltip.add(new Konva.Tag({
        fill: "#cccccc",
        pointerDirection: 'right',
        pointerWidth: 10,
        pointerHeight: 10,
        lineJoin: 'round',
        width: 80,
        height: 24
      }));
      g.add(tooltip);
        // edit button
        var btnEdit = MakeComplexText(
          {parent: g, pos: {x:0, y:0, w: 75, h: 24}, text: "Edit", textClr: "#666666", bgClr: "#cccccc", lineClr: "transparent", symbolLeft: "", symbolRight: "\uf14b", cornerRadius: 0}
        );
    layer1.add(g)

//    btnEdit.moveTo(layer1);



s1.draw()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.6.5/konva.min.js"></script>

<div id='container1' style="display: inline-block; width: 400px, height: 400px; background-color: silver; overflow: hidden;"></div>
```